# disable select drop down usingo jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using JQuery 1.8.3.
I need to disable all select drop downs which ever id starts with **rowNum** and i have below code for that.

```
 $('select[id^=rowNum]').prop("disabled","disabled");
```

Above code works only in IE. But in FF it is not working.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code works for me in FF
http://jsfiddle.net/7D4xL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('select[id^=rowNum]').attr('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('select[id^=rowNum]').prop("disabled",true);
```

Comment: i tried..not working...

Comment: Then you probably need to create a fiddle to demonstrate your problem.